# Facing problem while displaying data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display two columns( `dp` & `username`) inside a single hyperlink tag.

I cannot solve the problem.

Here is my code:

```php
echo "<a href='profile.php?user_id=".$row["user_id"]."'>"."<img src='$row['dp']'  width='15' height='15'>". $row['username']. "</a>"
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Is dp a path to an image?

Comment: @raffi did you see my answer?

Comment: @user2342558 I saw your answer but used the sprintf function from previous answer before you answered. Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate your dedication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid this kind of problems you can use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Like this:

```
echo sprintf(
    '<a href="profile.php?user_id=%s"><img src="%s"  width="15" height="15">%s</a>',
    $row["user_id"],
    $row["dp"],
    $row['username']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your echo html with this, You append syntax wrong `src='$row['dp']'` in img tag.

```
echo "<a href='profile.php?user_id=".$row["user_id"]."'><img src='".$row['dp']."'  width='15' height='15'>". $row['username']. "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must correctly escape what you insert in a double quoted string , like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"profile.php?user_id=$row[user_id]\"><img src=\"$row[dp]\" width='15' height='15'>$row[username]</a>";
```

As the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) says:

> If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the
>   following escape sequences for special characters:
>
> ```
> \n    // insert a new line
> \r    // insert a carriage return
> \t    // insert a tab
> \v    
> \e
> \f
> \\
> \$    // insert a literal $ without searching for a variable
> \"    // insert a literal "
> \[0-7]{1,3}
> \x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
> \u{[0-9A-Fa-f]+}
> ```

So, each `"` inside a string defined with `"` must be escaped like this: `\"`:
`$string = "\"";`

Also you don't need to exit string definition with the `.` to insert a variable or an array value, simply do this:

```
$string = "$variableName"; // for simple variable
$string = "$myArray[keyName]"; // for array's key access
$string = "{$myMultidimensionalArray['keyNameLevel1']['keyNameLevel2']}"; // for nested array's key access
```

And more, setting the `href` with `"` like this `<a href=\"` allows you to insert `'` inside it like this:

```
<a href=\"someUrlwith'...\"
```